Porque el value es 0 - C#
Estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de sacar el value al mandar el formulario, por algún motivo si lo escribo dentro del <option> me sale el valor pero a la hora de mandar el formulario me sale 0, a que se podría deber esto?
Código HTML
<InputSelect class="form-select" @bind-Value="suscripcion.IdDispositivo">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Selecciona un dispositivo</option>
    @foreach (var dispositivo in dispositivos) {
        <option value="@dispositivo.Id">@dispositivo.NumeroSerie - @dispositivo.Id</option>
    }
</InputSelect>

Apartado Code
@code{
[SupplyParameterFromForm]
private Model.Suscripciones suscripcion { get; set; } = new Model.Suscripciones();private List<Model.Dispositivo> dispositivos = new List<Model.Dispositivo>();

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync(){
    await GetSuscripcionDetalles();
    await GetDispositivosNoAsociados();
    suscripcion = new Model.Suscripciones();
}

}
Método
 var respuesta = await http.PostAsJsonAsync($"{Data.GlobalService.uri}/Cliente/enpoint?Id={Id}&IdDispositivo={suscripcion.IdDispositivo}", suscripcion);
 var rest = await respuesta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 if (respuesta.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
     navManager.NavigateTo("/usuarios/" + id + "/" + rol);
 } else {
     string errorMessage = await respuesta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 }

Clase Suscripción
 public class Suscripciones {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaInicio { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaAcabado { get; set; }
    public int IdCliente { get; set; }
    public decimal Importe { get; set; }
    public int IVA { get; set; }
    public bool Activa { get; set; }
    public int dispositivos_totales { get; set; }
    public int IdDispositivo { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public static string tabla = "tblSuscripciones";
}

Clase Dispositivo
public class Dispositivo {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdCoche { get; set; }
    public int IdModelo { get; set; }
    public string NumeroSerie { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaAlta { get; set; }
    public string IMEI { get; set; }
    public int Numero { get; set; }
    public static string tabla = "tblDispositivo";
}


Donde está inicializada la variable ?

Ola @Excorpion actualizo mi pregunta para que quede todo más concreto

Conseguí resolver el problema, por razones que desconozco funciana. Decidí modificar la siguiente línea de código
@code{
   [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    private Model.Suscripciones suscripcion { get; set; }
    // La anterior -> [SupplyParameterFromForm] private Model.Suscripciones suscripcion { get; set; } = new Model.Suscripciones();
}

Luego Quite la variable de sesion del OnInitializedAsync y la puse en el mismo método pero sin el Async
protected override void OnInitialized() => suscripcion ??= new();

Y con estás modificaciones el código ya funciona

Seguramente estas con server rendeirng (SSR) (cosa que deberías indicar en tu pregunta, junto con la versión de .net). En SSR estatico, cuando haces POST OnInitialized se ejecuta nuevamente lo que reasigna tu variable suscripcion, por eso la solución es usar el operador ??= que solo hará un new cuando suscripcion sea nulo

Muchas gracias @Yussef, ahora modifico mi pregunta adjuntando lo necesario :)
